# Call ojdbc in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, ojdbc

Using this [post](https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit) I want to create JUnit test with datasource. I tested this code:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

public class NewEmptyJUnitTest
{

    public NewEmptyJUnitTest()
    {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception
    {
        // rcarver - setup the jndi context and the datasource
        try
        {
            // Create initial context
            System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
            System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
                    "org.apache.naming");
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            ic.createSubcontext("java:");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

            // Construct DataSource
            OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
            ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db");
            ds.setUser("MY_USER_NAME");
            ds.setPassword("MY_USER_PASSWORD");

            ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/nameofmyjdbcresource", ds);
        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MyDAOTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void inittest() throws NamingException
    {

        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context webContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");

        DataSource ds = (DataSource) webContext.lookup("jdbc/nameofmyjdbcresource");

    }
}
```

But Netbeans cannot find this class 'OracleConnectionPoolDataSource'. How I can solve this problem?
What is the package that I have to import in order to use this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `ojdbc14.jar`, `OracleConnectionPoolDataSource` can be found in `oracle.jdbc.pool`:

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource;
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct but this package cannot be found in my local repository. What repository I need to as into Maven's POM file in order to download this package?

Comment: I doubt you're going to find Oracle's intellectual property in any public repository. Download the Oracle JDBC drivers and import them into your own repository instead. And be sure to test against different versions, especially if you want/have to provide backwards compatibility with old Oracle versions.